# Python Tinker Sqlite3 Retrieve Data and Show on Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a `database` with various tool components. I also have a page with fields that I would like to populate with data from the `database`. I have looked at a lot of docs for both `Tkinter` and `Sqlite3`, and can't figure out how to do this. It seems like it would be a simple thing to do, but nothing I try has worked. The code for the window I would like to populate is below. Can someone please show me an example of how I could get specific `table data` from the `database` to populate these fields? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code so far:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import sqlite3
     
    
    data = Tk()
    data.title("WellSav | Data")
    data.geometry("1400x800")
    
    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('well_sav.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    
    # Tools Frame Insert Data Into Fields
    
    tools_frame = LabelFrame(data, text="Tools Data", padx=5, pady=5)
    tools_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    
    tools_type_label = Label(tools_frame, text="Tool Type")
    tools_type_label.grid(row=0, column=0,)
    tools_type_entry = Entry(tools_frame)
    tools_type_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    tools_length_label = Label(tools_frame, text="Tool Length")
    tools_length_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    tools_length_entry = Entry(tools_frame)
    tools_length_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    
    tools_inside_diameter_label = Label(tools_frame, text="Tool ID")
    tools_inside_diameter_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    tools_inside_diameter_entry = Entry(tools_frame)
    tools_inside_diameter_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    
    
    tools_outside_diameter_label = Label(tools_frame, text="Tool OD")
    tools_outside_diameter_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
    tools_inside_diameter_entry = Entry(tools_frame)
    tools_inside_diameter_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
   
    
    data.mainloop()
```

Comment: is the database already created? waht abt the table?

Comment: @acw1668 so far nothing I have read and tried actually works. If it had worked, I wouldn't be asking here. Do you actually think I would spend time asking a question I already knew the answer to?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, the database and tables are created. When I SELECT * FROM my database table I get errors. The error message says it can't find the table. But when I enter data into it from the other pages, it works and shows up when I use the edit button. It is only when I try to display to a new page that I get the error messages.

Comment: new page? what do u mean by new page?

Comment: Then post what you have tried so far on how you get data from database and how you insert data to entries.

Comment: c.execute("SELECT * FROM tools) gives me this error:   File "data.py", line 14
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tools)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @CoolCloud I am trying to build a page that lists all of the tools and their data (length, width, tool number...etc). That is what the code I posted originally is trying to do. The page opens just fine, but I can't get it to populate from the database. I get the error:   File "data.py", line 14
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tools)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: u forgot to close the double quote " at the end . Like `c.execute("SELECT * FROM tools")`

Comment: @CoolCloud I am an idiot. And you are a super hero.

Comment: It happens while programming, nothing new. But is the doubt solved? and now uk that EOL eror is cuz of not closing " or ) or something ;D

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, now I know, and I have learned a valuable lesson. Thank you so much for your time and patience. As you probably guessed, I am very new to this.

Comment: me too, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

A `ttk.Treeview` without the tree part can be used to display a table:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(master, columns=('Position', 'Name', 'Score'), show='headings')
```

Then set the column labels with

```
tree.heading(<column>, text="Label")
```

and add rows with

```
tree.insert("", "end", values=(<position>, <name>, <score>))
```

The first argument is the item's parent, since you want a table, all items have the same parent, the root `""`. The second argument is the position of the new item in the tree.

Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def show():
    cr=sqlite3.connect('database_name')
    c.cursor()
    c.execute("select * from table_name")

    tempList = c.fetchall()
    tempList.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)

    for i, (name, score) in enumerate(tempList, start=1):
        listBox.insert("", "end", values=(i, name, score))

scores = tk.Tk() 
label = tk.Label(scores, text="High Scores", font=("Arial",30)).grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
# create Treeview with 3 columns
cols = ('Position', 'Name', 'Score')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(scores, columns=cols, show='headings')
# set column headings
for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)    
listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

showScores = tk.Button(scores, text="Show scores", width=15, command=show).grid(row=4, column=0)
closeButton = tk.Button(scores, text="Close", width=15, command=exit).grid(row=4, column=1)

scores.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

You can find more details about the `Treeview` widget [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190428233645/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html).